# Transpose flattened matrix of x,y pairs

Tags: python, matrix, transpose

I have been given a one dimensional array of decimal numbers which represent x and y values.

I need to transpose the given 1 dimensional array as if it were a matrix.

My current code does this, but not completely how I would like:

```
to_transpose = [0.914, 0.639, 0.058, 0.760, 0.926, 0.475,
                0.255, 0.671, 0.195, 0.966, 0.336, 0.841,
                0.279, 0.341, 0.591, 0.638, 0.520, 0.225]
matrix_width = 6
matrix_height = 3
# INITIALIZE AN EMPTY LIST
transposed_list = [None] * matrix_width * matrix_height

for w in range(matrix_width):
    for h in range(matrix_height):
        transposed_list[w * matrix_height + h] = to_transpose[h * matrix_width + w]
```

This code correctly transposes the matrix, but not in the format I am wanting.

Due to this being an array of x, y values, the desired output is shown below:

```
correct_output=[0.914, 0.639, 0.255, 0.671, 0.279, 0.341,
                0.058, 0.760, 0.195, 0.966, 0.591, 0.638,
                0.926, 0.475, 0.336, 0.841, 0.520, 0.225]
```

In the correct output, every 2 decimals is treat as 1 in the transpose.

1. I would like to know if this is possible within one pass
   through the matrix without use of external libraries, as in the
   above example?
2. I would like this to work on both a square and non-square matrix.

Comment: You asked for "no external libraries", but `numpy` would be perfect for this: `np.array(to_transpose).reshape((6,3)).T.ravel()`

Comment: Given that each 2 values belong together it should probably rather be something like `reshape(3, 3, 2)` or `(2, 3, 3)`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Agreed, I did not see that two-values-being-pairs thing at first.

Comment: @DominickSearle Your approach would work if you preprocessed your list to be `[(0.914, 0.639), (0.058, 0.760), ...]`.

Comment: Try to make a list of lists

Comment: It's easier if you first seperate your x and y values, or create (x,y) tuples first.

Comment: I need to write this code in a couple of different languages, so that's why there is no pre-processing or use of numpy unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you asked for a "no libraries" solution, I would very much suggest to use `numpy` for everything related to matrix manipulation, such as reshaping or transposing, both of which you will need here:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> to_transpose = [0.914, 0.639, 0.058, 0.760, 0.926, 0.475,
                    0.255, 0.671, 0.195, 0.966, 0.336, 0.841,
                    0.279, 0.341, 0.591, 0.638, 0.520, 0.225]

>>> np.array(to_transpose).reshape((3,3,2)).transpose(1,0,2).ravel()
array([ 0.914,  0.639,  0.255,  0.671,  0.279,  0.341,
        0.058,  0.76 ,  0.195,  0.966,  0.591,  0.638,
        0.926,  0.475,  0.336,  0.841,  0.52 ,  0.225])
```

Breaking this down a bit:

- `np.array` turns your list into an `array`...
- which you then `reshape` to `3x3x2`, i.e. a 3x3 matrix of tuples...
- which you then `transpose`, swapping the first (0) and the second (1) axis and keeping third (2) in place...
- and finally the matrix is flattened again with `ravel`

If you can't use numpy in the end, you could still use this to correctly transpose a matrix of indices to figure out which element has to go where, then reproduce that with a loop over the list `to_transpose`:

```
>>> list(np.array(list(range(w*h))).reshape((3,3,2)).transpose(1,0,2).ravel())
[0, 1, 6, 7, 12, 13, 2, 3, 8, 9, 14, 15, 4, 5, 10, 11, 16, 17]

>>> [i%2 + (i//2 * w % (w*h)) + 2 * (i//(h*2)) for i in range(w*h)]
[0, 1, 6, 7, 12, 13, 2, 3, 8, 9, 14, 15, 4, 5, 10, 11, 16, 17]

>>> [to_transpose[i%2 + (i//2 * w % (w*h)) + 2 * (i//(h*2))] for i in range(w*h)]
[0.914, 0.639, 0.255, 0.671, 0.279, 0.341,
 0.058, 0.76, 0.195, 0.966, 0.591, 0.638,
 0.926, 0.475, 0.336, 0.841, 0.52, 0.225]
```

Of course, you can also do the same with regular loops instead of list comprehensions and in other languages. Basically, each of the three terms in the addition of the index corresponds to one of the dimensions of the matrix, and to be honest, I figured this out more by guessing than by really understanding what's going on. Needless to say that the `numpy`-solution is much cleaner.

Comment: I will accept this answer as it is correct and quick. Thank you. But would you be aware of a method without using numpy (within the for loops)?

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on not using `numpy` for this, I'd recommend to either separate the x,y values, or tuple them together first:

```
to_transpose = [0.914, 0.639, 0.058, 0.760, 0.926, 0.475,
                0.255, 0.671, 0.195, 0.966, 0.336, 0.841,
                0.279, 0.341, 0.591, 0.638, 0.520, 0.225]
a = to_transpose

rows = 3
cols = 3
tot = rows*cols

# separated
x, y = a[::2], a[1::2]
xt = [x[i+j] for i in range(0, rows) for j in range(0, tot, cols)]
yt = [y[i+j] for i in range(0, rows) for j in range(0, tot, cols)]
transposed = [e for t in zip(xt, yt) for e in t]

# tupled
xy = [(i,j) for i,j in zip(a[::2], a[1::2])]
xyt = [xy[i+j] for i in range(0, rows) for j in range(0, tot, cols)]
transposed = [e for t in xyt for e in t]
```

It's quite obvious that even while this works, `numpy` will be a far better tool for this kind of operation.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/python3

to_transpose = [
    0.914, 0.639, 0.058, 0.760, 0.926, 0.475,
    0.255, 0.671, 0.195, 0.966, 0.336, 0.841,
    0.279, 0.341, 0.591, 0.638, 0.520, 0.225
]

matrix_width = 6
matrix_height = 3

to_transpose_with_pairs = [(to_transpose[2 * i], to_transpose[2 * i + 1]) for i in range(len(to_transpose) // 2)]
# [
#     (0.914, 0.639), (0.058, 0.76), (0.926, 0.475),
#     (0.255, 0.671), (0.195, 0.966), (0.336, 0.841),
#     (0.279, 0.341), (0.591, 0.638), (0.52, 0.225)
# ]

to_transpose_as_matrix = [None for _ in range(matrix_height)]

for row in range(matrix_height):
    start = row * matrix_width // 2
    end = start + matrix_width // 2

    to_transpose_as_matrix[row] = to_transpose_with_pairs[start:end]

# [
#     [(0.914, 0.639), (0.058, 0.76), (0.926, 0.475)],
#     [(0.255, 0.671), (0.195, 0.966), (0.336, 0.841)],
#     [(0.279, 0.341), (0.591, 0.638), (0.52, 0.225)]
# ]

transposed_as_matrix = list(map(list, zip(*to_transpose_as_matrix)))
# [
#     [(0.914, 0.639), (0.255, 0.671), (0.279, 0.341)],
#     [(0.058, 0.76), (0.195, 0.966), (0.591, 0.638)],
#     [(0.926, 0.475), (0.336, 0.841), (0.52, 0.225)]
# ]

transposed_with_pairs = [pair for row in transposed_as_matrix for pair in row]
# [
#     (0.914, 0.639), (0.255, 0.671), (0.279, 0.341),
#     (0.058, 0.76), (0.195, 0.966), (0.591, 0.638),
#     (0.926, 0.475), (0.336, 0.841), (0.52, 0.225)
# ]


transposed = [val for pair in transposed_with_pairs for val in pair]
# [
#     0.914, 0.639, 0.255, 0.671, 0.279, 0.341,
#     0.058, 0.76, 0.195, 0.966, 0.591, 0.638,
#     0.926, 0.475, 0.336, 0.841, 0.52, 0.225
# ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this to work in the way you wanted it to with just one pass through the matrix and without using any libraries.

```
to_transpose = [0.914, 0.639, 0.058, 0.760, 0.926, 0.475,
                0.255, 0.671, 0.195, 0.966, 0.336, 0.841,
                0.279, 0.341, 0.591, 0.638, 0.520, 0.225]
matrix_width = 6
matrix_height = 3
# INITIALIZE AN EMPTY LIST
transposed_list = [None] * matrix_width * matrix_height

for w in range(0, matrix_width, 2):
    for h in range(matrix_height):
        transposed_list[w * matrix_height + (2 * h)] = to_transpose[h * matrix_width + w]
        transposed_list[(w * matrix_height + (2 * h)) + 1] = to_transpose[(h * matrix_width + w) + 1]
print(transposed_list)
```

I did 3 things:

- Made w skip the odd values by using step value as 2
- Added an extra line, where the odd index element gets the value of y
- Finally doubled the value of h so that every alternate element gets a
  new value

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate it without numpy and in one line/pass, but it is terrible:

```
m=to_transpose # for easy writing only
[ n for l in zip( *[[(m[i],m[i+1]) for i in range(k,k+6,2)] for k in range(0,len(m),6)] ) for t in l for n in t ]
```

Use numpy instead.